# Error opening mobile network settings menu

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I would like to open the mobile network settings with this code:

---

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent();

intentSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intentSettings.setAction(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
             cont.startActivity(intentSettings);
```

---

but it gives me this error. Any ideas anyone?

```
12-10 11:17:34.902: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(623): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { action=android.settings.DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS flags=0x4000000 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get this working, change your intent creation to the following code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");
intent.setComponent(cName);
```

Basically the android manifest requires a component filter.

Comment: This is not working on Android 4.1 anymore, any idea how to do it there?

Comment: To make this work with Android 4.1, I removed the component... But I do not know why.

Comment: As CommonsWare notes below, this was a bug in Android =(#13368), which meant you must specify the component. I fixed this for Android 4.0, so the component is no longer required. As for Android 4.1, possibly the class name changed -- you cannot rely on these remaining constant across Android versions or device manufacturers.

Comment: @buzeeg hey can you please explain?
did you mean like this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6789616

Comment: @AmelJose hi! I made it work like that : https://github.com/buzeeg/datasettings/blob/master/src/com/remifayolle/android/datasettings/DataSettingsActivity.java

Answer (score 4):

You could try getting rid of the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, which may not be needed in this case, and see if that helps.

If that does not help, then either:

- You are running this on Android 1.1 or earlier (seems unlikely)
- You are running this on a device with a compatibility issue (if so, please let me know what device it is)
- Something really strange is going on

**UPDATE**

It appears the answer is the third bullet above. While `ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS` is in the documentation, the Settings application itself does not have an `<intent-filter>` for it.

I will check back when the Android 2.3 source is released and see if that changes the story any. If not, I will file a bug, because either it is a documentation error or a Settings application error, IMHO.

Comment: Was also interested why it does not work. Tried that without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, using the same approach that normally works for other Settings screens. Definitely it crashes on Nexus One. Really strange.

Comment: @Desiderio: See my update above -- the Settings app does not seem to support this action.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Looked like something of that kind.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I tested this on both 1.5 HTC Magic and 2.2 HTC Desire device. How can we follow up this bug? Will you come back to this thread and give us updates?

Comment: @dackyD: No sign of it being honored in Android 2.3 either, so I have opened an issue on it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13368

Answer (score 1):

This works the same for the ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS, just add the following component:

`Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);`

`ComponentName cName = new ComponentName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.Settings");`

`intent.setComponent(cName);`