# How do i redirect the user to Data Usage settings in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Like if i want to redirect the user to Location service i have to use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Now what shoulb the ACTION_ to let the user go to the data usage settings where he can enable the Mobile Data Traffic?

Comment: Looks like this might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000452/how-can-i-launch-mobile-network-settings-screen-from-my-code

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't looking for:

```
    final Intent dataUsage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    dataUsage.setClassName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity");
    startActivity(dataUsage);
```

Your title suggests that's what you want, but your comment suggests you wanted the network operator settings.

Comment: Yes but in network operator settings i have the option to turn on the internet. So ya previous solution works,so does this. Thanks anyways.