# Check if the user is connected to the internet and if not prompt the user to turn on data services android

Tags: java, android

I am making a check if the user is connected to the internet. If the user is not connected then prompt the user to turn on data services.

This is the code that I am using to prompt the user to turn on data services if not connected

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
    dialog.dismiss();   
}
```

The above code works fine but it opens the wifi settings. Please how can I modify the code to open the image shown below

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I launch mobile network settings screen from my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000452/how-can-i-launch-mobile-network-settings-screen-from-my-code)

Comment: @Mohit I have tried the options but did not work

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: using this function you can check the internet is connected or not in your device

Comment: I already have that code. I want to prompt the user to turn data services

Comment: Read my questions very well. How can I modify the code to display the image shown