# is there anyway to open sceret network settings in android studio through intent?

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to develop an android app(using java in android studio) like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gibatekpro.force4gltemodeonly&hl=en . But the problem I am encountering is that I don't know how to open these settings programmatically. These are mobile settings so there should be an Intent for this. I hope I have explained my problem well. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789616/5339146 this can help you to start.

Answer (score 0):

Its an example of opening GPS setting hope you get some help from it

```
//Declared  as class level constant

public static final int GPS_REQUEST_CODE = 9003;


//Intent wherever you want to set it 
  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, GPS_REQUEST_CODE);


//In On Activity Results

  if (requestCode == GPS_REQUEST_CODE) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            boolean providerEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (providerEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS not enabled. Unable to show user location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```